# Neon intrinsic vsubq_f32?

Tags: neon

When I use neon instructions to improve the performance of C functions, I encounter a problem
When I apply  vsubq_f32  instruction  to calculate :
float32x4_t A=vdupq_n_f32(259.235657) float32x4_t B=vdupq_n_f32(0.00001610) float32x4_t value = vsubq_f32(A,B);
I obtained the value :259.235626,why?
I think the right value should be 259.235641.Is there anyone who can help me out？

Comment: 256.235641 is indeed the expected output - but I can't see from your code as to why that's not what you're getting. I presume this is mock code to show the problem (it would be a very inefficient subtraction otherwise!) - are there other things to check that you are doing what you think you are? There's no overflows etc?

Comment: Can you share a complete minimal reproducer?

Comment: @BenClark, thank your reply!When I convert the data 259.235641 from float64 to float32, this data becomes 259.235626, I guess it is float32 overflow

Comment: It's not a neon problem, but a float one. 259235657 can't be expressed in 24 bits.